# IOS App starts with iPhone 4s layout on greater devices

Tags: ios

I just wanted to ask why my app is starting with a too small size on devices other than iPhone 4s on my simulator?  Is there something wrong related to the constraints I set or general project difficulties?

[image: IOS error scaling]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must set your launch images. At least set them for iphone 6 and you should solve the issue

[image]

[image]

Comment: No, do not do this. Instead of using launch images (which Apple is slowly deprecating), use the Launch Screen File.